# Which of the two, WebConfigurationManager or ConfigurationManager, to use from within a class library?

Tags: .net, configurationmanager, webconfigurationmanager

I have some code in a class library that reads stuff from the client application's configuration file.

Which of the two classes should I use to read the data? Should I use the `WebConfigurationManager` or the `ConfigurationManager` if I want my code to be right for all kinds of client applications that will use the class library?

Comment: This question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm

Comment: And this answer also helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061074/303685